# How would you put a shadow on a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, shading

I am creating a boxplot in R and want to add a shadow to the box(similar to the box-shadow property in CSS). I was wondering if this was possible and if so how would you do this? Thank You

Comment: Not an answer but my first response was: Don't! These type of pseudo-3d effects are in nearly all cases at best unnecessary and at worst distractive and annoying. Reminds me of Powerpoint/Excel graphics from the 90s. Nowadays clean 
 and flat graphics are (thankfully) the norm. `ggplot`/`ggtheme` and `ggpubr` provide some excellent themes for visualising data in a professional way.

Comment: I agree that the question is not so much "how" as "why" :) But if you must, I think it would better be created outside of R by editing the graphic.

Comment: You can get drop shadows with grid if you use an SVG device (though [it's not simple](https://community.rstudio.com/t/drop-shadows-on-geom-text/9251)), but I agree that this is an ill-advised approach. For text shadows are sometimes useful for contrast, but otherwise they're usually superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly an unpopular choice in terms of graph aesthetics, but if for some reason you do need to do it, one simple way to achieve the effect would be to just plot some grey rectangles underneath the boxes. Here's a quick and dirty example using the `mtcars` dataset.

```
#Plot and save the dimensions of the boxes   
b <- boxplot(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars)
```

This will return a list with an object `stats` that contains the y-coordinates of the boxes in the second and fourth rows. The default settings are to plot the first box at x=1 with a width of 0.8, so from x=0.6 to x=1.4 and so on.

```
#Pick some arbitrary offsets
xoffset <- 0.03
yoffset <- 0.3

#Add a dark gray rectangle slightly offset to each box
rect(0.6+xoffset, b$stats[2,1]-yoffset, 1.4+xoffset, b$stats[4,1]-yoffset, col="darkgray", border=NA)

rect(1.6+xoffset, b$stats[2,2]-yoffset, 2.4+xoffset, b$stats[4,2]-yoffset, col="darkgray", border=NA)

rect(2.6+xoffset, b$stats[2,3]-yoffset, 3.4+xoffset, b$stats[4,3]-yoffset, col="darkgray", border=NA)

#Replot the same boxplot on top of the rectangles using the `add=TRUE` argument. 
boxplot(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars, xlab="Number of Cylinders", ylab="Miles Per Gallon",
        add=TRUE)
```

You might want to make some adjustments so that the shadows are proportional to the size of the boxes. Art isn't my thing so I'm honestly not sure how that is supposed to work with light source and perspective etc. Again, you probably don't want to do this, but you can try it out yourself and see how it compares to the other better plotting options that `R` offers.

[image: boxplot with shadows]